Correct Expression for Centripetal Force
Assume we have a car of mass $m$ with an initial velocity of $u$ ms$^{-1}$ about to travel on a loop-the-loop that is made up of two semicircles, AB and BC, of different radii $R_1$ and $R_2$ where $R_1>R_2$ as shown below:

Note that the semicircle AB has radius $R_1$ and the semicircle BC has radius $R_2$.
The point A is where the car enters the loop-the-loop, and the two semicircles are joined smoothly at B.
My questions are about the centripetal force at the limits/boundaries between different parts of the track:

What is the centripetal force $F_c$ at point A? Is it simply equal to the normal reaction force from the ground (since A is still horizontal) or is it equal to $\frac{mu^2}{R_1}$ since this is where the circular path begins?

More importantly, assuming that the car has velocity $v$ ms$^{-1}$ at B, what is the centripetal force $F_c$ at point B? This is the boundary/limit between the semicircle AB of radius $R_1$ and the semicircle BC of radius $R_2$, so I have no idea what radius to use for the vertical centripetal force exerted (note that the car travels horizontally at this point).


Is $F_c$ at B equal to $\frac{mv^2}{R_1}$ since it is just leaving semicircle AB, or is $F_c$ equal to $\frac{mv^2}{R_2}$ as it is just starting semicircle BC?
Any help or ideas would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

There is a discontinuity in the force at each of these points. If this seems "unphysical..." well, yes, it is unphysical. Pointlike cars and perfectly circular roads are also unphysical.
The value precisely at that point is not really well-defined. But it also doesn't matter (as long as it's finite), because the car spends only an infinitesimal amount of time at that point. Just relax and choose either value, or the average, or whatever.

The other answers have correctly pointed out that there would be discontinuities. I want to point out that you seem to have an incorrect understanding of centripetal.
In the standard Newton 2nd Law expression, $\sum\vec F=m\vec a$, the left are causes, and the right are effects. You don't get to mix them up. You see something going around in a circle, then on the RHS you must have the centripetal acceleration. That is an effect. There may be no one force that causes the centripetal acceleration.
In particular, the force that is physically actually there, say at A, is the normal reaction force $N$, and at A, it transitions from $N=mg$ to $N=mg+\dfrac{mu^2}{R_1}$
Now, you take whatever time you need to absorb these facts. Centripetal is not a force, even if you can mathematically make it one. It is not a cause of motion, it is a deduction from observed motion, deduction from effect.

I'm not sure I've ever seen "centripetal" used as noun before, but I do like the idea of changing the nomenclature to break the apparent analogy between "centripetal force" and causes like "gravitational force" and "friction force". I like the idea of it as a deduction: you observe circular motion, so a force of certain magnitude toward the center must be supplied. Whether this force is supplied by gravity, friction, tension in rope, etc. is not known without more information.

Just like when launching off a ramp, the normal force goes from some value to zero in an instant, the same with the centripetal force at the transition, it instantaneously goes from one value to another. There is no requirement for smoothness when it comes to forces.

If you travel on a path $\vec r(t)$, parameterized by time $t$, then the arc-length is:
$$ s(t) = \int_0^t||\dot r(\sigma)||d\sigma$$
The tangent vector to the path is:
$$ \vec T = \frac{d\vec r}{ds} $$
and the curvature is:
$$ \kappa = \Big|\Big|\frac{d\vec T}{ds}\Big|\Big|$$
The centripetal acceleration is:
$$ a = \kappa \dot{r}^2 \hat N $$
where the normal is:
$$ \hat N = \frac{\frac{d\vec T}{ds}}{\Big|\Big|\frac{d\vec T}{ds}\Big|\Big|}$$
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet–Serret_formulas
So work it out for your $s(t)$. The centripetal force is going to be a mixture of gravity and "normal reaction force". but as pointed out in another answer: so what? Centripetal force is a function of the path, not forces.
Now I have a top tier PhD in physics and I have  no recollection of the term "normal reaction force" and have never used the concept in any answer to any question, nor at work (same for suvat). When did come into the lexicon? Why?
Based on the many questions I have read on this site, it only causes confusion.

In the real world you cannot change the velocity of a body instantaneously as this would imply an infinite acceleration and hence an infinite force to be acting on the body.
So you deal with a problem such as yours by assuming that the changing in velocity occurs over a time which is much less then the other times involved in the motion, effectively instantaneously and do not attempt to quantify the acceleration exactly at points of discontinuity in the curvature of the track.
Elementary Mechanics problems are strewn with such non-real situations.
For example you must have been asked about the motion of a body whose velocity time graph looks like a square wave and so has discontinuities in its gradient.
Questions like that are more concerned with what happens before and after the discontinuity rather than at the discontinuity.

to obtain a smooth path , you transfer the  path to  Euler spiral
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral,
you obtain $~x(s)~,y(s)~$ where s is the line element
the centrifugal force is:
$$\mathbf F=m\,\begin{bmatrix}
  \omega^2\,x(s) \\
  \omega^2\,x(s) \\
\end{bmatrix}\quad,\omega=\frac{v}{\kappa}$$
where $~\kappa~$ is radius of curvature
$$\kappa(s)=\frac{(x'^2+y'^2)^{3/2}}{x'\,y''-y'\,x''}$$
the velocity $~v=\dot s~$  you obtain from the equation of motion
$$m\,\ddot s=\ldots$$
for a straight line is the radius of curvature infinity, thus the angular velocity $~\omega=0~$

No smoothness path
straight line
$$x(s)=s\quad,y(s)=0
\\\kappa=\infty\\\omega=0
$$
circular path , radius r $$x(s)=r\,\cos(\frac sr)\quad ,y(s)=r\,\sin(\frac sr)\\
\kappa=r\\\omega=\frac vr$$
the equation of motion
$$m\,\ddot s=F_s~,v=\dot s$$
